# Angular directive as shorthand for multiple directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make an angular directive that combines `ng-mouseover`, `ng-mouseout`, and `ng-mousemove`.  Ideally, I'd like to have a custom attribute `hover="thing"` which, through a custom directive, would be shorthand putting all three of these mouse event attributes in an element, each calling some function with `thing` as a parameter.

Is there an easy way to do this?  I can use a template, but I want this directive to simply be able to be added to any existing element, from images to divs.  I don't want to have to make separate directives for every type of element I might want to use it on.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: can bind all those events using exposed `angular.element` in directive `link` function. Not clear what specific problem is. See `bind()` in docs for angular.element

Comment: What work have you done so far to solve the problem, and what difficulty are you having solving it?